# How can i change the wordpress admin fav icon?

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I am working on an wordpress site. I want to change the Favicon icon of my wordpress site admin. How can i change the favicon icon?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your function.php file

```
function favicon4admin() { 
    echo '<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/x-icon" href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/favicon.ico" />'; 
} 
add_action( 'admin_head', 'favicon4admin' );
```